Why does countability misbehave in intuitionistic logic
On page 3 of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2404.01256.pdf
I spotted the claim:

Definitions of countability in terms of injection into ℕ misbehave intuitionistically, because a subset of a countable set need not be countable.

I do not understand why it the case. If $A\to \Bbb N$ is injective and $S\to A$ is an inclusion of subset, isn't the composition $S \to A \to \Bbb N$ again injective?
May I please ask for an unfold of an argument here?

Even finiteness doesn't always behave the same as in classical logic -- for example, in intuitionistic systems, often being in bijection with ${ 0, \ldots, n-1 }$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is not necessarily equivalent to having an injective map to such a set, or to having a surjective map from such a set, or to the power poset being well-founded.

Right before this statement, the author defines a set $S$ to be countable if there exists a surjection $\mathbb{N} \to S + 1$. Classically, this is equivalent to the existence of an injection from S to $\mathbb{N}$, but constructively this need not be so. The argument is essentially as you've surmised. If you have a subset of a set equipped with an injection into $\mathbb{N}$, then that subset also has an injection into $\mathbb{N}$.
But the definition of countable used here doesn't have that property. If S is a set with a surjection $\mathbb{N} \to S + 1$ and $A$ is a subset of $S$, there need not exist a surjection $\mathbb{N} \to A + 1$. Check out this page on subcountability for more.

I don't know what property exactly the authors had in mind to use the normative word 'misbehave', but in any case the classical proof that countability (surjection) and numerability (injection in the other direction) can be defined from one another uses LEM resp. assumes the naturals to be well-ordered, and so the two properties are at least not coincidental in that context.
An arbitrarily complicated, say not computably enumerable index subset of natural numbers trivially injects back into $\mathbb N$. If a set $A$ injects into $\mathbb N$ you can see that as giving its elements a name. But as a domain, that subset of such finite ordinal names is also complicated in general.
If you know how to count in a surjection sense, then it means you can "stream" all its elements and that surely can be useful. Maybe best read the statement like that.
I try to come up with a construction on the spot, that also highlights the breakdown in the other direction of interest: Define a sequence $(x_n)_n$ of real numbers such that just $x_n=n$ (with $n$ on the right the natural in the reals) for all $n>0$ and let $x_0$ be some real which (maybe from its initial digit expansion) we can see to be necessarily very close to $1$ but the sharp equality $x_0 = 1$ shall be undecidable/independent. If we take the codomain to be the sequences range, it's surjective by definition. Classically either $x_0=1$ or not. If yes, then the identity on the positive naturals (a subsets of the reals) injects the image back into the naturals. If not, then we also have to deal with $x_0$ and we map it to $0$. The generic classical proof looks at the pre-image of naturals for any value in the codomain and chooses "the least of them", whatever it may be. But in general, we might not allow ourselves that luxury and here might simply not know what to do with the complicated looking $x_0$, and so fail to inject back.
